# Getting the Object Type from a Shared Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, object, pointers, types, shared-ptr

Is there a way to get the object type from a shared pointer? Suppose:

```
auto p = std::make_shared<std::string>("HELLO");
```

I want to get the string type from p i.e. something like:

```
p::element_type s = std::string("HELLO");
```

meaning: p::element_type is a std::string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shared_ptr::element_type` gives you the type held by the `shared_ptr`; you can access this type from `p` using the `decltype` specifier. For example:

```
int main()
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<std::string>("HELLO");
    decltype(p)::element_type t = "WORLD"; // t is a std::string
    std::cout << *p << " " << t << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as you've probably seen, per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), `std::shared_ptr` has a type alias `member_type = std::remove_extent_t<T>`.

to access it, you can do something like

```cpp
auto p = std::make_shared<std::string>("hello");
decltype(p)::element_type s = std::string{"heya"};
```

the type alias is associated to the class itself, not the specific member!
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/K9sWvecxd)

Comment: Or `decltype(*p) s`

Comment: You might want to re-read the page you linked to. The alias declared in `shared_ptr` is named `element_type`, not `member_type`.